# Java: Cómo puedo instanciar desde otro archivo .class que se ubica en el mismo paquete? Al compilar por cmd da error

Tags: java, cmd, compilar, packages

Estaba intentando programar solo con el bloc de notas y el cmd (se supone que ayuda a los novatos como yo, o al menos eso leí por ahí).

El punto es que cree un Prueba.java con este codigo:

```java
package carp;

public class Prueba
{
    public static void hablar()
    {
        System.out.println("Hola");
    }
}
```

Y otro Main.java

```java
package carp;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Prueba a1 = new Prueba();
        a1.hablar();
    }
}
```

Ambos se ubican en la carpeta `\test\carp` dentro del escritorio.

Cuando trato de compilar el primer archivo con `javac prueba.java`, no hay problemas. Sin embargo, cuando intento hacer lo mismo con el main.java, me apunta a la clase Prueba diciendo `error: cannot find symbol` en la línea 7

> Nota: También intenté agregarle un constructor a Prueba.java, pero tampoco funcionó.

Comment: No tiene nada que ver con tu error , pero el metodo `hablar()` es estatico puedes llamarlo usando simplemente `Prueba.hablar()`

Comment: A mi me ha compilado y ejecutado bien tal y como lo tienes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error que enfrentas viene dado porque no compilas todos los archivos fuentes de una sola vez.
Normalmente cuando se usa el comando `javac` **solo** compila el archivo que se le ha especificado en la linea de comandos, simple.

Cuando se tiene que compilar mas de un archivo están éstas alternativas (*asumiendo que estas ubicado dentro del directorio* `\test\carp`):

***- Listando cada archivo fuente:***

`javac Prueba.java Main.java`

***- Usando un wildcard para compilar todos los*** `.java`:

`javac *.java`

**EDITO:**

Al ejecutar `javac Main.java`, compilas ese y solo ese archivo que referencia a otra clase `Prueba` la cual NO esta especificada en el comando `javac` y por eso no va a encontrar dicha clase, lanzándote en este caso que no conoce lo que es `Prueba`.

No será de utilidad compilar cada fuente de manera separada, (Llamar a `javac` por cada archivo) sino ejecutar `javac` seguido de todos los `.java` que integran la aplicación.

Espero aclare tu confusión al momento de compilar por linea de comandos.

Answer (score 0):

Para mi es mucho mas dificil programar sin entorno de desarrollo (IDE). El ejemplo que tu pones funciona perfectamente en Intellij Idea aunque tal como te indican al declarar estático el método hablar() no hace falta instanciar. Has probado a poner todo en el mismo archivo? Quizás así no te de error

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Prueba a1 = new Prueba();
    a1.hablar();

    Prueba.hablar();
}
}

class Prueba {
    public static void hablar()
    {
        System.out.println("Hola");
    }
}
```